# Embed custom application in Microsoft Teams

Tags: microsoft-teams

We are planning to embed our application as a custom app in Microsoft Teams Tab.
Our application is based on AngularJS framework. I am wondering if it is possible or not?

Currently I created an App Manifest via App-studio in MS-Teams but when I "Test and Distribute" that app, the application is not loading inside the iframe tab and it keeps spinning.

I tried to run our application in an iframe in a simple HTML and it works fine but not inside Teams.
There is no error in console and I cannot understand what is going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

While this should be possible, it's important to understand the difference between "personal" and "shared" tabs - shared tabs need an "Configuration" experience upfront in order to set up the tab. In both cases though, you need to make sure to reference the Teams JS lib in order for your tab to actually render. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/create-tab-pages/content-page#integrate-your-code-with-teams) for more, where it states:

> For your page to display in Teams, you must include the Microsoft Teams JavaScript client SDK

Comment: Thanks Hilton, we are using "Shared" tabs. and  for sure we missed including SDK.

Comment: ok, hopefully that was the main issue? You can test it, by making a Personal tab, but if you want to make a Shared tab, you need to include a "configuration" page as well. It's basically what will appear in the small popup window when you add the tab. It gives you the change to perform any configuration you might need from the user (as an example, see the "SharePoint" tab, which requires the user to choose a page or a list in a specific site, etc.). You don't -need- to have any actual config, but you then just need a stub page that notifies Teams that the final tab is ready for rendering

Comment: I am still confused, the content page can be my web-application. correct?

Comment: yes, correct. In a "shared" tab though, you need to add an extra page in your project, that will appear first in the "configuration" popup, before the user sees your content page/tab

Comment: I am testing the app with personal tab first, I included Microsoft SDK in the code, but the app cannot render inside the team (testing on chrome browser). I get lots of error:
One of the errors is: Access to fetch at 'https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/json-schemas/teams/v1.9/MicrosoftTeams.schema.json' from origin 'https://dev.teams.microsoft.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Comment: What are you trying to fetch exactly? The link you've provided is NOT to the SDK, it's to a schema showing how to define your app for distribution..Please refer here for the right links: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/overview/msteams-client?view=msteams-client-js-latest

Comment: I try to render our application inside the personal tab in MSTeam. The above error is the error I am getting in browser. I included the SDK in the code https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/sdk/v1.6.0/js/MicrosoftTeams.min.js

Comment: I could fixed above issue by updating the SDK version from v1.6 to 1.9. but now I got another error:Refused to set the document's base URI to 'https://teams.microsoft.com/_#/conversations/General?threadId=19:a324d0ec8a704c61ae6e2daf357a82fd@thread.tacv2&ctx=channel' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "base-uri *.protection.outlook.com".

Comment: I don't know how I can post full stack-trace it is long and it won't fit here. And if I added new post, it got deleted.

Comment: more error: 0-angular-jquery.min-eee9041.js:114 2021-03-17T10:54:24.451Z ChannelService: Empty threadId
(anonymous) @ 0-angular-jquery.min-eee9041.js:114
e.logMessage @ 3.2-app.min-5dc2fb6.js:1
e.error @ 3.2-app.min-5dc2fb6.js:1
e.resolveTeamAndChannel @ 3.2-app.min-5dc2fb6.js:1
s.getPendingMembersService @ 3.1-app.min-74276cf.js:1
(anonymous) @ 3.1-app.min-74276cf.js:1
$broadcast @ 0-angular-jquery.min-eee9041.js:145
$destroy @ 0-angular-jquery.min-eee9041.js:141
t @ 1-vendor.min-3a81616.js:1

Comment: This sounds like an issue with your app itself, whatever it's trying to do, like set the main browser's url

Comment: Thanks Hilton, I checked Network tab in the browser to see if something is blocked or not, I find out that the size of login page (width and height) is set to 0, so I assume it is the problem. Is there any way I can set width and height in MS-Team iframe? {"service":"formService","methodname":"dataPush","args":{"formname":"loginPage","beanname":"","changes":{"size":{"width":0,"height":0}}}}

Comment: What login page do you mean exactly? Do you have login for your app? If so, are you using MSAL, or what exactly?

Comment: the login page of our application. For now it is only POC and we want to show that we can load our application inside MS-Team, if it was successful then we are planning to use MSAL.

Comment: Update, the issue was with "Loading Indicator" option, I unchecked that option and now our application rendered inside MSTeam. Thanks Hilton.

Comment: now the next step is to implement MSAL for authentication, currently we are using oAuth2 for the authentication we need to change it to MSAL.

Comment: ok great, glad it's sorted. That loading indicator can indeed be a problem - there's specific behaviour you need on your page to tell it when to go away, otherwise it's better not to use at all. It usually shows an an error though, rather than just stuck loading.

Comment: Regarding the auth, see here for a sample on SSO with Tabs: https://github.com/pnp/teams-dev-samples/tree/master/samples/tab-sso